# Не реагирует на сортировку вопросов (с мобильного браузера)

Tags: дефект, мобильная-версия

В мобильном виде не реагирует на меню сортировки вопросов : `новые/конкурсные/цитируемые ...`

*Android5.0 / Opera 37.0.2*

Comment: Подтверждаю. Есть такой глюк. В chrome проблем нет.